# Index.php redirects to somewhere else, how to find the file containing the html code

Tags: php, html, wordpress, xampp

I have a local server running using xampp. the on our website there is a link that users have to click to go to view some 3d images, that link goes to a file index.php , inside that file there is no code, but when using inspect element in chrome i can see all the code. I need to change a single line of that html code, yet changing it in 'inspect element' of course, doesn't save it permanently.

So i am looking for how to find the file containing the code so that i can do the changes.

here is what is within the index.php code when opened with sublime text editor

````
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );  ```
````

Comment: `define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);` edit your theme. `wp-content/themes/your-theme-name`

Comment: your question need more information. if you didn't know about wordpress so you have to look for it. also you have to know some about PHP. 

wordpress uses plugins and themes. in your case you have to know what is your active theme and which plugins are activated,

Comment: thanks for replying, my themes folder has some files , all of them dont have the html code showing on the browser. the index.php file is empty also

Comment: since i know the exact cde showing on the browser, i am now looking for a way to scan all my files on the wordpress folder to find any thats matches some of the code. so far the windows explorer has found no files with that code . i'm in a mess